# How to access app-specific storage and database of android applications?

Tags: android, database, local-storage, storage

i want to access app specific storage and database of apps.
example. accessing downloaded videos from prime or youtube.
How can i do that.

i did a few google searches but not found any relevant details?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.